# How to extract files from zip inmemory?

Tags: java, zip

I want to extract all files from a list inmemory, and have them in a list where each element contains one of the in the zip contained files:

```
    List<Resource> extracted = new ArrayList<>();
    UrlResource url = new UrlResource("http://path.to.file.zip");
    ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(url.getInputStream());
    ZipEntry zipEntry;
    while((zipEntry = stream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        extracted.add(new InputStreamResource(stream, zipEntry.getName()));
    }
```

The `extracted` list will contain several `InputStreamResources`, each for a file that is contained in the zip compressed archive. This is OK.

Problem:
Each `entry/ZipEntry` field of the `ZipInputStream` within the resources is null!

```
((ZipInputStream) extracted.get(0).getInputStream()).getNextEntry(); // == null for all entries!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each ZipEntry remains only valid until you call getNextEntry(). You have to extract it *before* calling getNextEntry().

Unfortunately its not clearly documented that it behaves that way, I had to guess (because a stream implies you see all data only once) and a look at the source code of getNextEntry() shows that the previous entry is closed in getNextEntry().

You best bet is to extract the entries in the loop and build your resources around byte[] (or something similar).